# Преобразовать ответ с бд в структуру dom

Tags: node.js, dom, mongodb

Добрый вечер. Как преобразовать ответ с бд(mongodb) в структуру dom. Запрос приходит но на страничке видна одна запись. А в коллекции их несколько. Вот код.

```
eventEmitter.on("collectionUserChat",function(callback){
        async.connectDB(function (db) {
            async.getCollection("userchat", db, function (collectionUserChat) {
                async.find(collectionUserChat,function(rezult){
                    async.toArray(rezult,function(data){
                        data.forEach(function(i){
                            callback(i);      
                        });
                    });
                })    
            });
        });
    });

        async.connectDB(function (db) {
        async.getCollection("userstest", db, function (collectionUserTest) {
            async.find(collectionUserTest,function(rezult){
                async.toArray(rezult,function(data){
                    data.forEach(function(i){
                        console.log(i);

                        eventEmitter.emit("collectionUserChat",function (u){

                            if(i["pass"] == pass){
                                res.render("chat", function (err, data) {
                                    jsdom.env({
                                        html: data,
                                        scripts: ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"],
                                        done: function (err, window) {
                                            var $ = window.$;

                                            $(".list-group").append($("<a/>", {
                                                    href: "#",
                                                    class: "list-group-item"
                                                }).append($("<h4/>", {
                                                    class: "list-group-item-heading"
                                                }).text(u)).append($("<p/>", {
                                                    class: "list-group-item-text"
                                            })));

                                            res.write(window.document.innerHTML, "utf8");
                                            res.end();    
                                        }
                                    });
                                });

                            }else{
                                res.render("error",function(err,data){
                                    jsdom.env({
                                        html: data,
                                        scripts: ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"],
                                        done: function (err, window) {
                                            var $ = window.$;

                                            res.write(window.document.innerHTML, "utf8");
                                            res.end();
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                        })
                    });
                });
            })    
        });
    });
```

async.js

```
var mongo = require("mongodb"),
client = mongo.MongoClient;
function connectDB(callback){
client.connect("mongodb://******************", function (err, db) {
    if(err){
        console.log("failed connect");
    }
    callback(db);
});
}

function getCollection(name,db,callback){
db.collection(name, function (err, collection) {
    if(err){
        console.log("missing data");
    }
    callback(collection);
});
 }

 function find(collection,callback){
collection.find(function(err,rezult){
    if(err){
        console.log("can not find field");
    }
    callback(rezult);
});
 }

 function toArray(rezult,callback){
rezult.toArray(function(err,data){
    if(err){
        console.log("err array");
    }
    callback(data);
});
 }

 function forEach(data,callback){
data.forEach(function(i){
    callback(i);
});
 }

function closeDB(db){
db.close(function(err,rezult){
    if(err){
        console.log("can not close connect");
    }else{
        console.log(rezult);
    }
});
}

exports.connectDB = connectDB;
exports.getCollection = getCollection;
exports.find = find;
exports.toArray = toArray;
exports.forEach = forEach;
exports.closeDB = closeDB;

console.log("async has require");
```

Answer (score 1):

pravelno bydet tak

```
done: function (err, window) {
    var $ = window.$;
    collection.mapReduce(mapreduce.map, mapreduce.reduce, {
        out: {
            inline: 1
        },
        verbose: true
    }, function (err, rezult, stats) {
        if (!err) {
            //console.log(rezult);
            for (var i = 0; i < rezult.length; i++) {
                $(".list-group").append($("<a/>", {
                    href: "#",
                    class: "list-group-item"
                }).append($("<h4/>", {
                    class: "list-group-item-heading"
                }).text(rezult[i]['_id'])).append($("<p/>", {
                    class: "list-group-item-text"
                }).text(rezult[i]['value'])));
            };
            res.write(window.document.innerHTML, "utf8");
            res.end();
        } else {
            console.log('err mapReduce');
        };
    });
}
```